# Init scripts and shutdown order in centos

Tags: linux, centos, service, init.d

My current issue is that I have a process hanging from supervisord that I want to make sure it gracefully sending network exists etc.., but by the time supervisor is brought down there is no network.

I've tracked this to the `/etc/rc0.d/` folder in here I can see how `K90network` will be executed before `S00killall` which takes care of bringing down services, supervisord included. I find odd that this is the ordering because looking at `S00killall` it has a piece of code to avoid bringing down the network in case its needed.

`[ $subsys = network ] && continue`

So, I am not sure how `S00killall` could ever prevent network from going down if network is explicitly brought down for rc0

I am using `CentOS release 6.8 (Final)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, `network` service is supposed to be stopped in runlevel `0` before the `killall` script is executed. "Killing" `K*` scripts are executed before "starting" `S*` scripts.

There's one exception when you have root filesystem mounted via NFS. "Killing" `network` script prevents from stopping the network to keep the root filesystem consistent. Here is the `stop` section of the script:

```
stop)
        [ "$EUID" != "0" ] && exit 4
        # Don't shut the network down if root is on NFS or a network
        # block device.
        rootfs=$(awk '{ if ($1 !~ /^[ \t]*#/ && $2 == "/" && $3 != "rootfs") { print $3; }}' /proc/mounts)
        rootopts=$(awk '{ if ($1 !~ /^[ \t]*#/ && $2 == "/") { print $4; }}' /etc/mtab)

        if [[ "$rootfs" == nfs* || "$rootopts" =~ _r?netdev ]] ; then
                net_log $"rootfs is on network filesystem, leaving network up"
                exit 1
        fi
```

For your "hanging" process, I would try to do the same. Put there a similar condition to keep the network up or reorder scripts so `supervisord` stuff is stopped before the `network` script is called.

Comment: Turns out there was a failure on the supervisor chkconfig call and it was not installing the K script in rc0